# Which is the best way to include Grails into Liferay?

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy, liferay, portlet

I'm trying to include Grails applications into a Liferay portlet. I tried the [Grails Liferay Portlets Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/portlets-liferay) but it did not work for me at all.

Does anybody know any other possibilities? **Which do you think is the best and why**?

Comment: how does this differ from your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926598 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integration of Grails into Liferay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926598/integration-of-grails-into-liferay)

Comment: It does not duplicate the other question, because the other tries to solve my problem with Grails Liferay Portlets Plugin, and this asks for other possibilites apart from the Grails Liferay Portlets Plugin

Answer (score 1):

We had our Grails project integrated with Liferay at one point but it was a mess.  Inevitably we pulled it out of Liferay and we were able to use Grails properly again.  In our instance the question became, why are we using Liferay and do we really need it?

Now if you have a requirement for Liferay you might try simply using Spring Portlet support and use parts of Grails you like but not fully integration.  Spring Portlets with Groovy were much easier and cleaner to do.  If you simply want Grails goodies for services etc. you can try deploying a Grails WAR on the same tomcat and expose services to your portlets through REST, Hessian, Burlap or some other easy service serialization mechanism in Spring/Grails.  In  this case you have a Liferay UI app that calls your Grails services.

Once again, try some options, then decide if you truly need (or have) to use Liferay.  With advances in Javascript UI packages, I'm not sure 'portlet' spec apps are as appealing as they once were and the word 'portal' is something that sounds good to management but inevitably means little to what needs to be implemented.